# C++ to C# conversion for const uint8*

Tags: c#, c++

is there a way to convert this:

```
function (const uint8* ptra, long src)
{

  const uint8* ptrb = ptra + src;
}
```

I've tried converting each const uint* to a byte[] but i'm not sure how to handle the ptra + src.
Thanks

Comment: It'd probably help to know your ultimate goal here (e.g. what is your code going to do with `ptrb`).

Comment: Decide, [tag:c#] or [tag:C++], but not both.

Comment: What is the context of this?  C# avoids pointers and memory management. There is likely a better solution, or this is possibly unnecessary in C#, but we need more info on why you believe this needs to be translated.

Comment: I am trying to convert a small section of a library that does some YUV scaling and conversion and the code is in C/C++ . I didn't want to include the whole C++ library to the c# application since it is huge. Hence the idea of converting just the needed routines but I ran into pointer conversion issues as pointed above. I was just including a small section of the C++ routine

Comment: Right, I was just wondering how the pointer was being used. Is the code making a copy of the array, iterating over it, etc. Knowing that might help answer your question. There generally isn't a direct translation of c++ pointer code to c#. Depending on your use case, you might be able to use the `fixed` keyword to work with pointers directly in your c# code.

Comment: @xQueryUser, take a look at this for more information on the `fixed` keyword in C#.  It'll allow you to work with pointers in small sections of code, which might be sufficient for what you're trying to do.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/fixed-statement

Comment: Hi, @xQueryUser, did you ever get this sorted out?

Comment: @wablab, hi, i am still going through the conversion and haven't had a chance to compile and execute the code yet but i am taking the unsafe/fixed keyword as a consideration in the code during the conversion. Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to have a single array that contains a_and_b elements

```
void SomeMethod(byte[] array, long offsetForBPart)
{
   //TODO is array big enough?
   var b0 = array[0+offsetForBPart]; 
   var b1 = array[1+offsetForBPart]; 
   var b2 = array[2+offsetForBPart]; 
   //You get the idea;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In C#, this is often not the best approach, but it does answer your question specifically.  You can use the `unsafe` and `fixed` keywords as follows:

```
public unsafe void DoSomething(byte[] data, long src)
{
    fixed (byte* ptra = data)
    {
        byte* ptrb = ptra + src;
        // do your work... e.g.
        //   ptrb[0] = 10;
        //   ...is equivalent to...
        //   data[src] = 10;
    }
}
```

To use this approach, you'll have to compile your code as 'unsafe'.  If you're using Visual Studio, you can right-click the project node in Solution Explorer and select Properties.  Under the Build tab of the properties pages, check the 'Allow unsafe code' box.